# Delete lists that have a certain amount of elements in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, variables

I have the current list

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['A', 'B', 'D'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['A', 'C', 'D'],
 ['B', 'C', 'D']]
```

I want to delete the list ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']. Is there any way to do this by checking inside the list and removing the list if it has more than 3 elements?
Thanks

I know I could iterate over the whole list, and add the elements where the lenght is 3. But I don't think it is very efficient

Comment: Use a list comprehension that checks `len(element)`

Comment: or if you are a beginner use a loop that checks the each element of the larger list and keeps it if it satisfies your condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension!

`[ x for x in array ]`

will return the array as is. `x` represents an element in the array, in your case, the sub-arrays that you want to check the length of.

You can add a condition to this to filter:

`[ x for x in array if ... ]`

This will return the array but only for elements `x` that pass the condition after the `if`.

So you will want to check the length of x using the `len` function. In this case, your list comprehension should only include `x` when `len(x) <= 3`

In the spirit of learning I haven't given you the literal answer but you should be able to piece this information together.

Play around with list comprehensions, they are very powerful and constantly used in python to transform, map, and filter arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
b=[['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['A', 'B', 'D'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['A', 'C', 'D'],
 ['B', 'C', 'D']]
c=[]
for i in b:  
    if len(i)<=3:
        print(i)
        c.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This script creates a new list by parsing through each index of the original list and getting the length of it. If the length is 3 then it gets added to the new table, if it doesn't have a length of 3 then it gets forgotten about

```
newlist = [] 
for a in range (0, len(oldlist)):
    if len(oldlist[a]) == 3:
        newlist.append(oldlist[a])
```

Comment: there is no need for `range` here you can just do `for a in oldlist`